# SOAP, How to get data from secound service

Tags: python, api, soap, wsdl, zeep

Im try to take data from API with SOAP.
Everything works, but i have 2 Services on that API.
First one is for test, and it works. But data its 'hiden' on secound.
How can i get there?
I use zeep.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone need answer:
You need to add 'service_name='TergProductsDataService' to connect to the second service.